# Math formulas on a static HTML page

Tags: forms, formula

I need to create the below on my page but don't know how to code it. I am not a programmer so please be as specific as possible. Thanks.

If you have [ -- USER INPUTS VALUE HERE -- ] referrals and they refer [ -- USER INPUTS VALUE HERE -- ] who refer [ -- USER INPUTS VALUE HERE -- ] more, you will earn [ -- VALUE BASED ON FORMULA* HERE -- ].

**The formula is: VALUE 1 {times} dollar value {plus} VALUE 2 {times} different dollar value {plus} VALUE 3 {times} third different dollar value*

Comment: I guess you are asking for a piece of javascript that updates the last "field" based on the input in the other "fields" ?

Comment: Why the downrating?  Seems like a valid question

Comment: Seriously, this is a valid question. Downvoters, try asking the OP to clarify his question instead of jumping on the downvote button.

Answer (score 3):

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), something like this:

```
If you have <input type="text" name="referrals"> ....
<input type="text" name="refer"> ... <input type="text" name="refer2">
... <span id="value"></span>
```

Then the script:

```
jQuery().ready($('input').change(function()
{
    var referrals = $('input[name=referrals]').val();
    var refer = $('input[name=refer]').val();
    var refer2 = $('input[name=refer2]').val();
    var dollarValue = 12.3;

    var value = dollarValue * referrals;
    value += dollarValue * refer;
    value += dollarValue * refer2;

    $('#value').text('$' + value.toFixed(2));
}));
```